# streaming MKV files from windows home server

Tags: streaming, home-server, matroska, windows-home-server

I recently installed WHS 2011 and setup streaming and successfully have streamed movies and music but i noticed that i cannot find any of my MKV files. I realize that microsoft stated that MKV is not supported for streaming but does anyone know of a workaround or possibly another OS that can do what WHS can do or even better?

I have a AMD quad core 2.8GHz and 8gb of ram so hardware wise the computer can handle streaming just fine.

I went with WHS only because it had everything I wanted and basically sets itself up but if their is a Linix os that can do the same and work with MKV im open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a codec pack like [Sharky](http://shark007.net/), as this has proven to be a solution for some people.

You could try adding other software like [Twonky](http://twonky.com/) or [PS3 Media Server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/) (no, you don't need a PS3) and using that to stream your MKV files.  [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) can also work to stream media.

You could also look closer as to whether or not you need to be using MKV files at all, and you could convert them to a format that WHS will recognize.  [VideoHelp](http://www.videohelp.com/) is a great source of info on that.

Comment: Awesome I will give them a try! Now will those additional software be able to stream to external networks like WHS can?

Comment: All of them should be able to if ports are forwarded correctly, but I know for sure that VLC can.